# JSF page template - control parameter for style attr value

Tags: java, jsf

I'm looking for a solution of adding a value for a style property of an xhtml page component.
It could be control or HTML element both cases suits me fine.

Here's an example of the idea

```
<ctrl:ctrlName ..... style="The_Parameter" />
```

or

```
<div ..... style="The_Parameter" />
```

If someone happens the be familiar with this or any technique that could help, I do appreciate your kind help, BR

Comment: Erm, do you mean something like `style="#{someBean.someProperty}"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use an EL expression referencing a bean property in the `style` attribute of a JSF component and even a plain vanilla HTML element.

E.g.

```html
<h:panelGroup layout="block" style="#{bean.style}">...</h:panelGroup>
<div style="#{bean.style}">...</div>
```

with

```java
private String style;

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    style = "background: pink;"; // Or something dynamic.
}

public String getStyle() {
    return style;
}
```

I'd only prefer `styleClass` resp. `class` over `style` by the way. Separate style from markup (and model).

Comment: true, but in my case I need dynamic value

Comment: Change the `init()` method in the example accordingly to initialize it "dynamically" (e.g. external file, DB entry, etc).

Answer (score 1):

if can specify a parameter like this `<div ..... style="${parameter}" />`

assuming you set that parameter before.

if you are using jstl you could use for instance:

`<c:set var="parameter" value="width: 400px;"/>`